# How can I get and send to the last row submitted?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've built a script that will get the issue with a form submission (D2) then output the text with the information in an email. Right now the Email address location (B2) and issue (D2) are hard coded. How can I work the code to get the email and issue from only the last row submitted?

```
    function SendNot() {
      // Fetch the Issue
      var reasonRange =                                 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TriggerSettings").getRange("D2"); 
      var reason = reasonRange.getValue();
      // Check for Issue

      if (reason==="nogps"){
        // Fetch the email address
        var emailRange = 
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PlayerInfo").getRange("B2");
        var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
        // Send Alert Email.
        var message = 'No GPS...'; 
        var subject = 'Latest VDGL Entry...';
        GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      }

       else if (reason==="nobarcode"){
        // Fetch the email address
        var emailRange = 
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PlayerInfo").getRange("B2");
        var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
        // Send Alert Email.
        var message = 'No Barcode...'; 
        var subject = 'Latest VDGL Entry...';
        GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
       }
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling your function? Are using an on form submit installable trigger?

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the last row with content using the following method:

```
sheet.getLastRow()
```

In your example you can calculate this as follows:

```
var d_size = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TriggerSettings").getLastRow();
var b_size = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PlayerInfo").getLastRow();
```

and then you can use **d_size** to grab the last row reason elements:

```
var reasonRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TriggerSettings").getRange("D"+d_size);
```

and **b_size** to grab the last row email elements:

```
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PlayerInfo").getRange("B"+b_size);
```

You can also use a different syntax to get the desired range:

- Instead of `getRange("D"+d_size)` -> `getRange(d_size,4)`
- Instead of `getRange("B"+b_size)` -> `getRange(b_size,2)`

---

#### References:

[Sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)